# "pip" is an unknown command in vs cood program

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip

When I wanted to install the cowsay library, the pip command does not run and I get this error

```
pip: The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
 pip
 ~~~
   CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The pip command should have worked for me and the cawsay library should have been installed but it was against my wishes

Comment: Either `pip` is not installed at all, or else you have not added its location to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: You can try `python -m pip install cowsay`, in case you don't have the `pip` alias on your PATH.

Comment: try `pip3` instead. If not, this all depends on how you'fe installed python and the environment you're using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+The+term+pip+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't added python to environment variables.
Follow this process

1. type edit env variables in search bar of your laptop and add  Python Scripts to PATH
2. After making changes to the PATH, restart your command line or PowerShell session to apply the changes.
3. Open CMD and check with command: pip --version